# Redefine label in enumerate list

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate

First: Some days ago I posted this question on [The LaTeX Community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=22255) but I have not gotten an answer so I post it here.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[danish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\newcommand*{\hv}[1]{\label{eqn:#1}\stackrel{\mathclap{(#1)}}{=}}
\newcommand*{\fk}[1]{\item[\eqref{eqn:#1}]}

\begin{document}

We have
\begin{align}
  \Delta y
  &\hv{1} m(x_{0}+h) - m(x_{0})\\
  &\hv{2} \frac{f(x_{0}+h)}{g(x_{0}+h)} - \frac{f(x_{0})}{g(x_{0})}\\
  &\hv{3} \frac{f(x_{0}+h) \cdot g(x_{0})}{g(x_{0}+h) \cdot g(x_{0})} - \frac{f(x_{0}) \cdot g(x_{0}+h)}{g(x_{0}) \cdot g(x_{0}+h)}\\
  &= \dots
\end{align}
Explanations:
\begin{enumerate}
  \fk{1} A
  \fk{2} B
  \fk{3} C
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Issues:

1. This way of refering to the lines in the align expression seems wierd. Is there a better way of doing this?
2. I will like the labels `(1)`, `(2)`, ... to be printed above `=` only and not flushed right too. I there a way of doing this?

Ad 2. I have tried putting `\notag` at the end of each line but then I get the following error:

```
Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'eqn:1' will be lost.
```

Comment: Ad 1: Yes, that is the purpose of the “flushed-right” equation-number. Ad 2: With `\notag` there is no actual equation-number to refer to. I would at least use `(\theequation)` instead of `(#1)` above the `=` to get the right `\eqref` later. `#1` is only the name of your label (`\label{eqn:#1}`), not the actual number of your equation. The label can be any arbitrary text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I initially thought of suppressing the equation numbering, and using a custom numbering, but it turns out that `\refstepcounter{...}` was being ignored at runtime inside the math environment.

Managed to get a workaround, which produces the following output. I started the equation numbering at 10, to make sure the numbers correlated.

The key was in the label being assigned inside `\makeatletter` to `\makeatother` via the `\ltx@label` variable. The base numbering was suppressed via `\begin{align*}` to `\end{align*}` math environment.

**The following is a sample output:**

[image: Output]

**Which was produced with the following code:**

```
\documentclass[danish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\usepackage[color]{showkeys}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}

\setcounter{equation}{10}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\hv}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{equation}%
    \ltx@label{EQ:#1}% Label%
    \stackrel{\mathclap{(\theequation)}}{=}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\fk}[1]{\item[\eqref{EQ:#1}]}

\begin{document}
We have
\begin{align*}
  \Delta y  &\hv{A} m(x_{0}+h) - m(x_{0})\\
            &\hv{B} \frac{f(x_{0}+h)}{g(x_{0}+h)} - \frac{f(x_{0})}{g(x_{0})}\\
            &\hv{C} \frac{f(x_{0}+h) \cdot g(x_{0})}{g(x_{0}+h) \cdot g(x_{0})} - \frac{f(x_{0}) \cdot g(x_{0}+h)}{g(x_{0}) \cdot g(x_{0}+h)}\\
            &= \dots
\end{align*}
Explanations:
\begin{enumerate}
  \fk{A} DESCA
  \fk{B} DESCB 
  \fk{C} DESCC
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My Pleasure....